# Should we user Request and Response model same?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

As a good API writing practice should we use request and response model separate or common?

Ex.

```
public abstract class BaseModel 
{

    public DateTime CreatedOn {get;set;} 

    public int CreatedOn {get;set;} 

}

public class UserModel : BaseModel
{

    public int UserId {get;set;}

    public string UserName{get;set;}

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    string _name;

    public string Name
    {

        get { return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", FirstName, MiddleName, LastName) }

        set { _name=value; }        
    }
}
```

Now if I'm creating API

```
CreateUser(UserModel uModel)
{
}

GetUsers()
{    
    // Here I'm returning all users from the system, so each user's object will contains CreatedOn and CreatedBy, which I don't require in the API response    
}
```

So here should we need to create multiple `UserModel` ?

Comment: Some people prefer using plain non inherited objects as data contract models. Some people even only use structs. Its smart to not inherit because by changing base class you will change a lot of API calls at once.

Comment: Often you'd have separate models for input and output yes. You might even have several different models (and methods) for each action, depending on the circumstances. It all comes down to what suits your application and business requirements to be honest. There's no "right" answer. It's good to write efficient and re-usable code but not at the expense of meeting the requirements accurately. Also consider testing - one change to your base model will require every single API method to be re-tested (and potentially the tests themselves to be updated).

Comment: I see no point to having the `_name` field and the `Name` setter.

Answer (score 0):

If your response format is json, one solution is using  [ScriptIgnore] annotation such that :

```
 public abstract class BaseModel
{
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public int CreatedOn2 { get; set; }

}
```

So that you can use your common class with not serializing unwanted fields for your api.